# Solving limit without L'Hopital (can't finish)

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-3}{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}} $$

Im kind of a noob in this site, and it look like my questions miss some context, so im going to to the best I can to give it.

Here is what I tried and the farthest i got, I dont know how to continue:[image: This is where i could get]

Im sorry if this is not what context means.

Comment: with our without L'hopital?

Comment: without, im sorry, its corrected

Comment: The limit is $\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$. please make your answers to come out to this. :)

Comment: Your context is fine. However, please learn [LaTeX to type mathematics on Math SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) because images are no good for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write the term in the form
$$\frac{(\sqrt{2x+1}-3)(\sqrt{2x+1}+3)(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2})}{(\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2x+1}+3)}$$

Comment: I got there, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{2x+1}-3=u\implies2x=u^2+6u+8$

and $\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt2=v\implies x= v^2+2\sqrt2v+4$

and as $x\to0; u,v\to0$

On division, $2v^2+4\sqrt2v=u^2+6u\iff v(2v+4\sqrt2)=u(u+6)$

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-3}{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}}=\lim_{u,v\to0}\dfrac uv= \lim_{u,v\to0}\dfrac{2v+4\sqrt2}{u+6}=?$$

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457481/limit-evaluation-conjugate-method-further-algebraic-manipulation/2459113#2459113

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-3}{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-3}{x-4}}{\frac{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}}{x-4}}=$$

$$=\frac{\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-3}{x-4}}{\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}}{x-4}}$$

If you can use derivatives, then $$=\frac{(\sqrt{2x+1})'\bigg|_{x=4}}{(\sqrt{x-2})'\bigg|_{x=4}}$$

Or you can calculate, e.g., $\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-3}{x-4}$ by multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}+3}{\sqrt{2x+1}+3}$ and using the formula $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint use the definition of derivative at x=4 as follows 
$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-3}{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}} =
\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-3}{x-4}
\cdot\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{2}}=(\sqrt{2x+1})'
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x-2})'}\Big|_{x=4}
 = \frac{1}{3}\frac{2\sqrt2}{1}$$

Comment: This is correct, but I can´t use definition of derivative. Thanks anyway

Comment: why can you not use the definition of derivative?